# Is there a way to contain bootstrap-vue in a wrapper class so that it doesn't conflict with other bootstrap libraries on the page?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, sass, bootstrap-vue

I am writing an app with Vue that is meant to be included on my clients' websites as a little on-page widget.  Those client websites may or may not be using Bootstrap.  Those that do use Bootstrap are conflicting with the bootstrap-vue built into my Vue app, which is causing all sorts of display issues within my app as well as the rest of the website.

Before using bootstrap-vue, I tried just using Bootstrap in my Vue app, and I was able to add a class wrapper around each Bootstrap module in the SCSS config, like in the code snippet below, and that worked great for the CSS.  My app relies heavily on modal pop-ups and unfortunately the javascript portion of Bootstrap was conflicting.

I decided to try bootstrap-vue, to avoid those javascript conflicts.  The modals work great now, but I have not found a way to contain the bootstrap-vue CSS to my own wrapper class.  It looks like bootstrap-vue only works when the bootstrap is included at the original, root level.  Any time I try to wrap any portion of bootstrap-vue or Bootstrap with a class, it won't compile.

I have tried a multitude of things like this, which works when using Bootstrap alone, but not with bootstrap-vue:

```
.mywrapperclass {
     @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
     @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/modal";
     @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
     @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/code";     
     ...
     
     @import "node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss";
}
```

Does anyone know how I can keep my app's bootstrap-vue css contained to a class and not affect the page as a whole?  If not, is there a way to do this with Vuetify or any other packages that may help me to achieve this while also providing modal pop-up functionality?

Comment: The code example should work just fine if you're using `SCSS`, except you're missing the required bootstrap SCSS modules `variables`, `functions`, and `mixins`. What error are you getting when compiling? Also be aware that some components will need extra work, to work correctly as they're appended to `<body>` by default. Stuff like `modals`, `tooltips` and `popovers`.

Comment: @Hiws Thanks for validating that I was on the right track.  By including the functions, variables, mixins modules and using javascript to hack in some wrappers around the generated modal divs to add my wrapper class, I got it compiling and everything seems to be falling into place now.

Comment: For `<b-modal>` you can use the `static` prop, to stop them from rendering at the end of body. And for `<b-popover>` and `<b-tooltip>` you can use the `container` prop.

Comment: @Hiws Thanks again, the static prop makes the b-modals work much better!